# Plotting multi repetitions in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following dataset:

```
Class      R1    R2    R3    R4    R5
Operator   6.5   2     18    3.6   5.1
Assest     1.3   9.5   6     6.3   7.5
Operator   10    5     9     2.2   7.5
Execute    6.3   4     2.5   9     9
Execute    6     5     5     5     1.6
Assest     6     2.5   6.6   7     7.9
Operator   10    5     13    5   7.5
Assest     5     2.5   6.6   9     7.9
```

I would like to generate a mulitplot for each class where each individual plot represents a single run (each multiplot will have three plots based on the example).

I started by doing the following:

```
data <- read_csv("/home/adam/Desktop/dataa.csv")
dataset <- data %>% melt(id.vars = c("Class"))
p2_data <- dataset %>% filter(Class == "Operator")
pp2 <- p2_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Class, colour=Class)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(0, 1000, 100)) +
```

but that only give me a plot of one class with all the runs, which is not what I want. Can you please help me solving this?

Comment: You misssed to include some information. Your colnames are `c(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5)`. But in your plot it is `x=variable, y=value`. How you transform your data?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but is `facet_wrap("Class")` what you're looking for? You should be able to add that into your code like `p2_data %>% ggplot(...) + geom_line() + facet_wrap("Class") + scale_x_discrete(...)` to get what you need.

Comment: @brittenb I want to generate a plot for each class (call it `plotX`). This `plotX` consists of three plots where each one of them represents one row of data.

Comment: @AdamAmin ... you may need to include an image of your desired output. This may involve using Paint or other image application to sketch out what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you would like to have separate plots for each of the three `Class`es with a line for each row of observations (3 for `Assest`, 2 for `Execute` and 3 for `Operator`), perhaps the below would help?

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  mutate(run=row_number()) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = c("Class", "run")) %>% 
  mutate(run=as.factor(run)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, colour=run, group=run)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Class)
```

[image]